# Android - Desktop icon for a program

Tags: android

Hi
Suppose I have written a little program and designed a icon, how can I apply this icon to the program?

seems that I can't find the solution at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set an icon for the application, in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, use the `android:icon` attribute in the `<application>` element - see [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#icon) for more.

For example `<application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon.png" ... >`.

Comment: This will add an icon only to the application list view. How do we add a desktop icon ?

Comment: Find the icon in the application view list, then click and hold it... the view will switch to your desktop and you can drop it there wherever you want.

Comment: @Steve 
Sure, but when I install eg. Evernote, its shortcut is added on desktop automatically. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Put the the icon in drawable folders. 
If you have 3 types of drawable folder(drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi) then put the icon file with the same name in all these folder. If you donot have these directories you have only drawable directory you can put there also.

let the icon name is icon.png
In ANdroid Manifest file `AndroidManifest.xml` use the `android:icon` attribute in the `<application>`
For example

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: This will add an icon only to the application list view. How do we add a desktop icon ?

Comment: @Jaseem desktop icon means? can you explain briely or attach any screenshot if possible

Comment: I meant home screen icons. Can we add them automatically when an application is installed ?